# Why the PCA image doesnt resemble the original image at all?

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, pca

I am trying to implement PCA without any library for image dimension reduction. I tried the code in the O'Reilly Computer Vision book and implement it on a sample lenna picture:

```
    from PIL import Image
    from numpy import *

    def pca(X):
        num_data, dim = X.shape

        mean_X = X.mean(axis=0)
        X = X - mean_X

        if dim > num_data:
            # PCA compact trick
            M = np.dot(X, X.T) # covariance matrix
            e, U = np.linalg.eigh(M) # calculate eigenvalues an deigenvectors
            tmp = np.dot(X.T, U).T
            V = tmp[::-1] # reverse since the last eigenvectors are the ones we want
            S = np.sqrt(e)[::-1] #reverse since the last eigenvalues are in increasing order
            for i in range(V.shape[1]):
                V[:,i] /= S
        else:
            # normal PCA, SVD method
            U,S,V = np.linalg.svd(X)
            V = V[:num_data] # only makes sense to return the first num_data
        return V, S, mean_X
img=color.rgb2gray(io.imread('D:\lenna.png'))
x,y,z=pca(img)
plt.imshow(x)
```

[image: original image]
[image: PCA image]

but the image plot of the pca doesnt look like the original image like at all.
As far as i know PCA kinda reduce the image dimension but it will still somehow resemble the original image but in lower detail. Whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, nothing is wrong per se in your code, but you're not displaying the *right* thing if I do understand what you actually want to do!

What I would write for your problem is the following:

```
def pca(X, number_of_pcs):
    num_data, dim = X.shape

    mean_X = X.mean(axis=0)
    X = X - mean_X

    if dim > num_data:
        # PCA compact trick
        M = np.dot(X, X.T) # covariance matrix
        e, U = np.linalg.eigh(M) # calculate eigenvalues an deigenvectors
        tmp = np.dot(X.T, U).T
        V = tmp[::-1] # reverse since the last eigenvectors are the ones we want
        S = np.sqrt(e)[::-1] #reverse since the last eigenvalues are in increasing order
        for i in range(V.shape[1]):
            V[:,i] /= S

        return V, S, mean_X

    else:
        # normal PCA, SVD method
        U, S, V = np.linalg.svd(X, full_matrices=False)

        # reconstruct the image using U, S and V
        # otherwise you're just outputting the eigenvectors of X*X^T
        V = V.T
        S = np.diag(S)
        X_hat = np.dot(U[:, :number_of_pcs], np.dot(S[:number_of_pcs, :number_of_pcs], V[:,:number_of_pcs].T))      

        return X_hat, S, mean_X
```

> The change here lies in the fact that we want to reconstruct the image using a given number of eigenvectors (determined by `number_of_pcs`).

The thing to remember is that in `np.linalg.svd`, the columns of U are the eigenvectors of X.X^T.

When doing that, we obtain the following results (displayed here using 1 and 10 principal components):

---

```
X_hat, S, mean_X = pca(img, 1)
plt.imshow(X_hat)
```

[image]

---

```
X_hat, S, mean_X = pca(img, 10)
plt.imshow(X_hat)
```

[image]

PS: note that the picture aren't displayed in grayscale because of matplotlib.pyplot, but this is a very minor issue here.